# DeferredResult for asyn processing between two different rest applications

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have 2 applications which are both rest API's built in spring. Need is to use asyn processing , will make call from APP1 to APP2 using RestTemplate and APP2 will immediately sends response back to APP1 saying "Request submitted". But in the background APP2 will still be running as we are using DeferredResult. Once the processing is finished does DeferredResult will send the response back to APP1 to do further processing say "Job finished " or "Job Error" something like this?

Comment: You can make the request processing asynchronous within the App, but the HTTP protocol itself is inherently synchronous. If the waiting time is not too long, you can just make the request and handle the request asynchronously and hope that it finishes before the timeout. But there are no async submit - replies possible in HTTP.

Comment: It should be async as APP1 uses RestTemplate to make a call to APP2. So basically APP2 does some file generation or I/O and send the delayed response. Any suggestions please

Comment: Your question is not clear and detailed enough, I have trouble understanding you. Anyway, here is an article on creating Asynchronous controller methods in Spring: https://niels.nu/blog/2016/spring-async-rest.html  Maybe that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Apologies for that , will check tht if it address my prb...